# How to apply [weak self] to a swift function (not closure)

Tags: ios, swift, closures, weak-references

Say I have a network function that has a completion and I use it multiple times in my consumer like this:

```
class Network {
   func getNumber(completion: @escaping (Int) -> ()) {
      //some network code
      completion(5)
   }
}

class MyClass {
var num = 0
let network = Network()

func myFunc() {
    network.getNumber { [weak self] (number) in
        self?.num = number
    }
}

func myFunc2() {
    network.getNumber { [weak self] (number) in
        self?.num = number
    }
}

}
```

and to avoid duplicate code i replace the closures with a single function 
like this:

```
class MyClass {
var num = 0
let network = Network()

func myFunc() {
    network.getNumber(completion: self.handleData)
}

func myFunc2() {
    network.getNumber(completion: self.handleData)
}

func handleData(_ number: Int) -> () {
    self.num = number
}
}
```

The problem With this approach is that I am unable to capture `self` as `weak` in the `handleData` function.

The problem could be easily avoided by changing the `handleData` to be a `closure` like this:

```
lazy var handleData: (Int) -> () = { [weak self] in
    self?.num = $0
}
```

So my question is: is there a way to apply `weak self` for a **function** and not only a closure?

Comment: You don't really need to worry about a weak self in this case since there is no retain cycle.

Comment: You are right. allow me to edit the post :)

Comment: Even with your edit there is no retain cycle because the `getNumber` function doesn't hold a reference to the closure on a property. It is simply held on the heap. In most cases with completion handlers you do not need to worry about the whole weak self dance.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this if you want to use `weak` reference to `self` on it's funcitons:

```
class MyClass {
    var num = 0

    func myFunc() {
        Network.getNumber { [weak self] in
            self?.handleData($0)
        }
    }

    func myFunc2() {
        Network.getNumber { [weak self] in
            self?.handleData($0)
        }
    }

    func handleData(_ number: Int) {
        self.num = number
    }
}
```

Also, you don't have to provide `-> ()` for a function that returns nothing.

Comment: are you sure you read my entire question from the beginning? I literally brought this in the first snippet

Comment: How do you expect the outcome would look like? I don't think any other way to achieve what you want is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account that `handleData` can be really big, how about

```
func myFunc() {
    Network.getNumber { [weak self] i in self?.handleData(i) }
}
```